# Wordpress behind nginx proxy - Loading failed for the <script> with source error

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, proxy

Recenty I setup Nginx reverse proxy(container which provide https for all pages) and Wordpress container behind it with a lot of other services like Nextcloud.

All services works fine except Wordpress which blocks css and js files by default when I access it through proxy but when I go to wordpress proxy, everything works(but only with http).

I added this line to wp-config.php and this fixes css loading

```
if ( (!empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'])) ||      (!empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) ) {     $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on'; }
```

But still I have errors with script loading - This errors are shown when I open console in Firefox

```
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://qqqqqqqq/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=5.3.2"
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://qqqqqqqqq/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=5.3.2”
```

I checked that this error(similar) shows in Firefox, Falkon and Brave.

[Image with error(click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x7pq.png)

This is my Nginx proxy setup

```
server {
listen       443 ssl;
server_name  site.pl www.site.pl;

location / {
resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
set $upstream_server wordpress;

  proxy_pass http://$upstream_server:80;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
}
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.pl/cert1.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.pl/privkey1.pem;
}
```

Comment: My first thoughts is that `qqqqqqqq` can only be coming from WordPress itself. It's important that WordPress is configured to use the correct site URL. See [Changing the Site URL](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/).

Comment: This qqqqqq I changed(I don't want to post url to my site here) and it is correct site URL.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having the same problem with style sheets and scripts not loading. Feels like I've tried everything by now and nothing works. The weird part is that some style sheets and scripts are loaded but some are not and I can't find why that is.

Comment: I'm not sure if I fixed it, because I don't use wordpress now, but in my notes I have this solution:
- Install wordpress with broken js and css
- After instalation in `wp-config.php` put one line below `<?php` line with `$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';`
- Restart server